# Split string data into multiple columns access

Tags: string, ms-access, vba

I have a column with multiple service codes that I am looking to split into different columns for tallying purposes in Access. An example of one line looks like this:

```
$= ** ;= AA AC BB1 CA5 CC4 CC5 CC6 CC7 CC9 CD1 CI CR D0 D1 D2 D3 D9 F> F> FA7 FA9 FB1 HA6 KJ P* P? PW PZ QG V4 WJ 1D 2O
```

The goal is to create an AA column, an AC column etc to tally which service code is being used for what row. Also each line of service codes is uniquely different from the others. Any thoughts? I'm kinda familiar with macros and SQL queries too.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub splitColumn()

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Integer

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM _Raw")
arr = split(rst("Serv Cde String"), ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
  '/do something here
Next i

End Sub
```

Thank you,

Rebecca

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45312091/edit) the question and include your code there.  Apart from code being almost unreadable in comments, the question itself is where all the needed information should be placed.

Comment: This question is essentially identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315638/split-one-field-column-into-multiple-columns-with-varying-figure-counts-sql-acce, both the sample data and intent.  Is this perhaps a homework problem? That's okay, but see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Splitting/parsing a string should be a separate question from how to store the parsed data.  At least you should show more work about how you plan on organizing / storing the split data and then ask for more specific help.

Comment: Here's a hint:  You probably need another table with at least two columns: the original primary key value plus a separated code field, especially since you have various, possibly unique codes.  You probably don't want to try creating separate columns for each code.  Then you'll have to write queries to do the "tally".

Comment: Don't duplicate questions. Add the required information here.

Answer (score 0):

The separator seems wrong:

```
Sub splitColumn()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM _Raw")
    arr = Split(rst("Serv Cde String").Value, " ")

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
      '/do something here
      Debug.Print i, arr(i)
    Next

    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I create a new field/column to tally the specific service codes used per row?