# Split one field/column into Multiple Columns with varying figure counts SQL Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Access, I need to write a SQL query to separate these rate codes into separate fields/columns from looking like this:

```
$= ** ;= AA AC BB1 CA5 CC4 CC5 CC6 CC7 CC9 CD1 CI CR D0 D1 D2 D3 D9 F> F> 
FA7 
FA9 FB1 HA6 KJ P* P? PW PZ QG V4 WJ 1D 2O

$= ** ;= AA AJ BB1 CA5 CC4 CC5 CC6 CC7 CC9 CD1 CI CR D. D0 D1 D2 D3 D9 FA7 
FA9 
FB1 HA6 I} KJ P( PW PZ QG V4 1A 1D 2V 3}
```

To this:

```
AA BB1 CA5 P?
AA BB1 CA5
```

I've researched this topic extensively but there is no question regarding lines with varying figure counts. I know there will be a lot of columns but that's what is desired.

Table Name: _Raw

Field Name: Code

Comment: Is that 6 separate lines? Is there really a blank line after the first 3? This will probably require VBA custom function code.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of various other questions.  Try searching for `[ms-access] split string field` and it returns many related questions/answers, too many to list here.  Your set of "varying figure counts" is probably too specialized to warrant its own question unless you have another more specific problem. It will at least require multiple steps 1) parsing string into separate values and 2) taking the new values and placing them into separate fields and/or rows.

Comment: More specifically, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312091/split-string-data-into-multiple-columns-access with the same data and intent.  Looks like a homework problem to me, so please see my comments on that question also.