# Access Query To Split String (with unordered variables in it) Into Columns BUT Output Is Ordered (each variable into a column with like)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know enough to be dangerous in ms access, but a query with this level of functionality escapes me.

**The Problem:**
I have an export of 100K+ products from a website to massage to import into another system. But I need to convert a string into separate columns in a clean way. This column contains product variable fields as a string separated by a delimiter (type, length, color, etc). The problem is the order of these don't line up so I can't just do a text to columns.

**Example Input:**

| Product | Field1 |
| --- | --- |
| Product 1 | `Type=Multiple;Side=Optional;Front=No;Hardware=Steel` |
| Product 2 | `Length=130 ft.;Type=Cable` |
| Product 3 | `Type=Foam;Ratings=Medium` |

**Example Output:** (in no particular column order):

| Product | Type | Side | Front | Hardware | Length | Ratings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Multiple | Optional | No | Steel |  |  |
| Product 2 | Cable |  |  |  | 130 ft. |  |
| Product 3 | Foam |  |  |  |  | Medium |

These stack overflow questions are very close but I'm not seeing how to convert it to this application. Thoughts?

- [Split string data into multiple columns access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312091/split-string-data-into-multiple-columns-access)
- [Split one field/column into Multiple Columns with varying figure counts SQL Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315638/split-one-field-column-into-multiple-columns-with-varying-figure-counts-sql-acce)

Comment: If these so-called "columns" like Type, Side, Front, Hardware, Length are fixed and known, then can we just create a query to select expected value from those text in their respective fields like:
Select Product, SplitFind(Field1, "Type") as Type, SplitFind(Field1, "Side") as Side, ..., ... from exampleInputTable

Comment: I doubt SQL alone can accomplish. VBA could split string to enter data directly into appropriate fields or as records in a table with fields: Product, Category, Data - then a CROSSTAB query could pivot Data into columns with Category as headers.

Comment: As @NSubedi describes, a VBA function could be called from a query. And as stated, it does require knowing exactly what categories would be present. Other VBA approaches would not need that. However, consistency in structure is vital when parsing string. If the semi-colon and = sign are dependable, this is doable.

Comment: @June7 Yes I can pull all of these categories so they are known. I was able to use the GetData function for each variable/column name by stringing a bunch of GetData("Hardware",[Field1]) AS Hardware together for each field.

THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @June7 I spoke to soon! Auditing the results I did find one additional caveat I overlooked. I don't know how many products are affected by this but there are instances of a category being duplicated (intentionally).

An example of this is length:
Length=20 ft.;Length=30 ft.;Length=50 ft.;Length=65 ft.;Type=Cable

Is there a way to account for this? Even if I can just flag records like this for manual review I think that would work. If multiples exist, in a "Multiples" column make it equal True?

Comment: And how many categories could have this? This will require more complex VBA. Consider my other suggested data structure and code. However, this now also makes a CROSSTAB more complicated.

Comment: @June7 your updated script was able to pull it all appropiately. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a function that returns data part.

```
Function GetData(strF As String, strS As String)
Dim aryS As Variant, x As Integer
aryS = Split(strS, ";")
For x = 0 To UBound(aryS)
    If Split(aryS(x),"=")(0) = strF Then
        GetData = Split(aryS(x),"=")(1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

This version allows for multiples of same category in field:

```
Function GetData(strF As String, strS As String)
Dim aryS As Variant, x As Integer
aryS = Split(strS, ";")
For x = 0 To UBound(aryS)
    If Split(aryS(x), "=")(0) = strF Then
        GetData = GetData & Split(aryS(x), "=")(1) & ","
    End If
Next
If GetData <> "" Then GetData = Left(GetData, Len(GetData) - 1)
End Function
```

Example of calling function from SELECT query (could be used for an INSERT INTO SELECT) for one field:
`SELECT Product, GetData("Type",[Field1]) AS Type FROM Table1;`

Any process dependent on knowing beforehand what categories will be present will fail if new categories are encountered.

Following code writes records to a ProductSpecs table with fields Product, Category, Data.

```
Sub StringToRecords()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, db As DAO.Database, aryS As Variant, x As Integer
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1")
Set db = CurrentDb
Do While Not rs.EOF
    aryS = Split(rs!Field1, ";")
    For x = 0 To UBound(aryS)
        db.Execute "INSERT INTO ProductSpecs(Product, Category, Data) " & _
                   "VALUES(" & rs!Product & _ 
                   ",'" & Split(aryS(x), "=")(0) & "','" & Split(aryS(x), "=")(1) & "')"
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Code could be modified to write data directly to a table designed with category fields. However, this would not be a strictly normalized structure and major pitfall already mentioned.